# How can I do rotating polygon on the background?

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-plugins, polygon

I'd like to create a polygon like on picture below, but it should rotating and bouncing between the borders of a web page, also it should be at the background and doesn't interfere with other elements of a web page.

I can do this in pure JavaScript with a lot of math, but maybe there's another approach which can simplify this task?

[image]

UPDATE: It need to work without user actions on Safari/Chrome/FF, at least few latest releases of these browsers, and mobile devices of course.

Comment: check out http://threejs.org/

Comment: `Your graphic cards doesn't seem to support WebGL`, it's solvable issue, but I'd like that it will support at lease last versions of Safari/Chrome/Firefox browsers. Anyway thank you it looks promises :)

Comment: Requesting a library for this purpose is offtopic for StackOverflow. If you change your question to say "how do I do this" in stead it would be a good fit. Anwers are then free to use a library if needed.

Comment: @Paul-Jan, I've changed according to your remarks. Thank you for pointing to it.